# How to check if exists array[i][j] in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexof

I have two dimensional array of chars, where all numbers, excluding one * (as given in picture (two examples) 
[image]

My task is to sum up all neighbour integers ( in example 1, neighbours of * are 4,2,5,8 and sum is 4+2+5+8=19)
But in example 2, * doesn't have **top** neighbour.

My initial code was like:

```
arr[i-1][j] + arr[i+1][j] + arr[i][j-1] + arr[i][j+1]
```

> But then I understood that in case like *a[0][-1]* doesn't exist. So can you help me to to solve my problem

Comment: `if(j >= 0 && j < 4)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly check each one. The following should work:

```
bool inRange(int i, int j) {
    const auto n = 4;   // you need to set this somewhere, or pass it in
    return (i >= 0) && (i < n) && (j >= 0) && (j < n);
}

auto sum = (inRange(i-1, j) ? arr[i-1][j] : 0)
    + (inRange(i+1, j) ? arr[i+1][j] : 0)
    + (inRange(i, j-1) ? arr[i][j-1] : 0)
    + (inRange(i, j+1) ? arr[i][j+1] : 0);
```

You can probably write this a little cleaner, but you need to check not only for the -1, but also for when you go over 3.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple solutions to this problem, but if you want to avoid checking bound each time you can extend the matrix dimension by 1 than needed. That means if you have an array:

```
1  *  4  7
8  9  2  3
5  1  2  4
4  3  6  5
```

Implement it as:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  *  4  7  0
0  8  9  2  3  0 
0  5  1  2  4  0
0  4  3  6  5  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Doing this won't even affect your sum at the end.

Comment: Of course you can do this with less copying by only copying and filling the subset you need - i.e. the square around the *.